# How to put a list inside a list ? I'm not sure im correct

Tags: python

I would just like to know how(in python) could I do the following. The players are : [Sam [ ] , Bob [ ] , Joe [ ] ]. Then what i'm trying to do is to put cards(list) inside each player. Example: Player 1 : Bob [Card1, Card2, Card3].
Thank you ~

Comment: show what you have attempted, explain what about it isn't working and what is confusing you

Comment: You should use a dictionary for this. `{"Sam": [], "Bob": [], "Joe": []}`. Read about Python dictionaries [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: Here is a list inside a list: `[[]]`

Comment: where are the players stored? In instances of a class? (e.g. Player) or would the list be something like `[['Sam', ['cardname1', 'cardname2', 'cardname3']], ['Bob', ['cardnameX', 'cardnameY']]]`? Or in a dictionary, as suggested by @John Gordon?

Comment: this site encourages questions which show coding work attempted, next time - to avoid getting negative votes - post your questions with self contained minimum code to reproduce your issue - welcome to SO

Comment: @RyanHaining Sorry, I should've clarified. Players are inside a variable which the user has entered.So the number of players is X and their names Y. Then what I need to do is to take 7 cards from my deck and give it to the corresponding player.

Comment: @ScottStensland my code has 70 lines so I tried to do a tl;dr

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary, keyed on each player's name:

```
players = {
    'Sam': [card1, card2, card3],
    'Bob': [card4, card5, card6],
    'Joe': [card7, card8, card9],
}
```